# Errors when updating angular version 10 to 11

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules

I've been updating the version of an angular version, I used the angular update guide, and used ng update @angular/core@11 @anuglar/cli@11, for the most part I was able to get it all done but when I try and do ng server, I get this error [Picture of terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3GCr.png)

Here is my Package.json
[Packag.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqzBR.png)

I have tried deleteing node modules and packag-lock and doing npm install, but I still get the same error when doing ng serve.

I know that my @angular/material isn't the same version as the rest of my angular, when I update my material version it just causes more and more errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your node modules are probably still cached. Try the following command

npm cache clean --force

then do npm install again